# Gulp didn't install on Laravel Homestead VM (from Windows) and no node_modules folder exists in the directory with package.json?

Tags: laravel, gulp, node-modules, homestead, laravel-elixir

I got Laravel Homestead up and running, except when I issue this ssh command:

```
gulp
```

I get this error:

```
Local gulp not found in ~/projects/laravel
Try running: npm install gulp
```

That's when I noticed there was no **node_modules** folder at all in this directory. Weird. Is this an issue where the paths were too long for Windows when I did a `vagrant up`? Since the host machine for this VM is Windows and I'm sharing folders with my VM (*actually I'm not, but rather I'm using phpStorm's sync so that pages will load faster on the VM*), when I do a `npm install` am I still going to encounter the problem? Hmm...I guess Taylor Otwell is using a Mac for development. Anybody have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Yes it appears to be that some of these paths from these package installs are too long for Windows. This means you can only install the gulp package after your VM is up. Here's what I did: (I also include a step for use with phpStorm already ([since it will keep server pages loading faster on the VM](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1757-slow-responses-on-homestead/0))

1. SSH into the VM and create a folder called `node_modules` in your project's directory (the directory where package.json is).
2. In phpStorm, go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment` and click on the `Excluded Paths` tab. Click the `Add deployment path` button and add the folder `node_modules` from step 1.
3. SSH back into the VM and in your projects folder (should be directory folder with package.json) and run this command: `npm install`. This will install all packages listed in your package.json file locally to the directory you are in, and will put the necessary files into the folder `node_modules`.
4. Now run the gulp command: `gulp`

**UPDATE:**

If you really prefer file-sharing through a **mounted folder**, then I've created a Gist that will guide someone through all the challenges I faced and had to resolve, including how to successfully run `npm install` in the guest environment: 
[Laravel Homestead for Windows (includes fixes)](https://gist.github.com/prograhammer/9493ee04f30dd74e121b)

Answer (score 0):

You should first [install node](https://nodejs.org/download/) in your local machine.

Then, navigate to your project folder and delete node_modules directory.

Run on your local machine inside project directory:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

Comment: No this won't work. One reason is that the file paths are too long for Windows. Then you have to consider some installs use symlinks.

Comment: I had the same problem and this was the solution.

Comment: I encountered issues like posted here: https://harvsworld.com/2015/how-to-fix-npm-install-errors-on-vagrant-on-windows-because-the-paths-are-too-long/. If you aren't having problems running `npm install` from your host environment then there's no fuss. But I do have a Gist I made (see my answer) that will help if you if you get to a point where you need it installing inside the guest. :-)